# Silverlight - INotifyDataErrorInfo and complex property binding

Tags: .net, silverlight, validation

I have a view model implementing INotifyDataErrorInfo. I am binding a textbox to one of the view model properties like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelfAppraisal.DesiredGrowth, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  Height="200" 
                         TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

The data binding works, but the UI is not responding when I add validation errors like this:

```
// validation failed
foreach (var error in vf.Detail.Errors)
{
    AddError(SelfAppraisalPropertyName + "." + error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
}
```

After running `GetErrors("SelfAppraisal.DesiredGrowth")` in the immidiate window, I can see:
`Count = 1

[0]: "Must be at least 500 characters. You typed 4 characters."`

I've made sure that the concatenation when adding an error matches the binding expression on the textbox, but the UI doesn't show messages as it was before I switched to using a complex type.

What am I doing wrong? Does validation with INotifyDataErrorInfo support this?

### Update

My viewmodel, which implements INotifyDataErrorInfo does raise ErrorsChanged when adding/removing errors.

```
protected void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (ErrorsChanged != null)
        {
            ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you raise the ErrorsChanged event?

Comment: Yes I am raising that even in my viewmodel when adding/removing errors.

Comment: Thanks, person that upvoted this. It would be awfully cool to not have to wrap properties on this object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` is watching the `SelfAppraisal` object for error notifications. It appears that you are adding the error to the object with the `SelfAppraisal` *property*. Try adding the error to the `SelfAppraisal` object:

```
foreach (var error in vf.Detail.Errors)
{
    SelfAppraisal.AddError(error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
}
```

This will raise the event on the instance that the `SelfAppraisal` property. The `TextBox` looks for an error with the `DesiredGrowth` name as it is bound to that property.

Perhaps it helps to state that the `TextBox` is not watching the root object for an error with a property name of `SelfAppraisal.DesiredGrowth`.

**UPDATE:** Use the ViewModel pattern to your benefit. Create a property on your VM:

```
public string SelfAppraisalDesiredGrowth
{
    get { return SelfAppraisal != null ? SelfAppraisal.DesiredGrowth : null; }
    set
    {
        if (SelfAppraisal == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (SelfAppraisal.DesiredGrowth != value)
        {
            SelfAppraisal.DesiredGrowth = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelfAppraisalDesiredGrowth");
        }
    }
}
```

Bind to this property:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelfAppraisalDesiredGrowth, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True,NotifyOnValidationError=True}"  Height="200" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Use the VM property when validating:

```
// validation failed
foreach (var error in vf.Detail.Errors)
{
    AddError(SelfAppraisalPropertyName + error.PropertyName, error.ErrorMessage);
}
```

Comment: SelfAppraisal doesn't implement INotifyDataErrorInfo. Can I instruct the textbox to watch the view model for the event and still bind to a property of a property?